# parameter cant have the value of null because of its type, but implecit default value is null?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

const LeftBar({Key key, @required this.barWidth}) : super(key: key);
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur8Ct.png)

here i am getting error at key and barWidth

Comment: Add the code snippet for better understanding of the issue

Comment: SizedBox(
                height: 10, ),
              LeftBar(
                barWidth: 40,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              LeftBar(barWidth: 70),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              LeftBar(
                barWidth: 40,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              RightBar(barWidth: 70),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              RightBar(barWidth: 70),